# iOS take messages between service and client with DNSServiceBrowse and DNSServiceBrowse

Tags: ios, bluetooth, multiplayer, nsnetservice

I am trying to implement a conversation with iPhone/iPad devices using DNSServiceRegister to register devices and DNSServiceBrowse to find services and resolve.

How can I send messages between the 'client' and the service?
there is any listener that I can put on the service to listen for messages via socket?

Answer (score 0):

There is a delegate you have to set when you start browsing for devices and there is `– netServiceBrowser:didFindService:moreComing:` where you have to "resolve" the service ... after that (another delegate with `- (void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:`) you can get In/Out sockets with `getInputStream:outputStream:`. after that you can start communication. You can find more here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Introduction.html or here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html there is also example WiTap which doeas basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

these methods netServiceBrowser:didFindService:moreComing: - (void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:), etc,.. works great using NSNetService to register a service.
I my app I am using DNSServiceRegister to register the service, which is a low level API:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/dns_discovery_api/Articles/registering.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002478-SW1

I am able to register the service, browse for the service and resolve, but I don't know what to do on the service side to listen for messages coming from the 'client' connected.